# Make "lessons" another synonym of the "study" tag

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I just noticed there's a single-use [lessons](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lessons) tag.

I could just replace it with [study](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/study) but it's a great synonym that will probably be created again and again so let's just add it. We already have all these other synonyms: "studying", "learning", "courses", "schools", and "students".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine our site without your outstanding tag-work.
Done.